# Rails mime type header for JSONP requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonp, mime-types

I am struggling to get a JSONP request to return as type "application/javascript" instead of "application/json".

***Source:***

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :json
...

class WeatherController < ApplicationController
  def forecast
    if params[:lat].blank? || params[:lng].blank?
      respond_with({ :error => 'Must provide lat and lng' }, :status => :bad_request,
                :location => :nil)
    end

    forecast = WeatherService.forecast_io(params[:lat], params[:lng], params[:time])
    if forecast != nil
      respond_with(forecast, { :location => nil, :callback => params[:callback] })
    else
      respond_with({ :error => 'No weather data' }, {
        :status => :not_found,
        :callback => params[:callback]
      })
    end
  end
```

When attempting to use `respond_to :js` and force the javascript format for testing, I get:

***Url:*** `http://localhost:3000/forecast/42.2214941/-83.4638431?callback=jQuery20301419312770012766_1386953327718&_=1386953327719`
[image: "Unknown format" error]